# vim: auto-expand only fold in .pm file after loading file?

Tags: perl, vim, folding

Here is my entire `.vimrc`:

```
set ignorecase
set scs
let perl_fold=1
hi Folded cterm=bold ctermfg=yellow ctermbg=lightblue
set modeline
set hidden
```

When loading a `.pm` file (which usually contains just a single `package`), all of the file's code is folded into a single line, and the first thing I have to do is to expand that fold.

Is there a way to have `vim` automatically expand that fold after loading the file? I em envisioning some sort of post-load hook which would allow me to say if the entire file (or more than 90%) is folded into a single line, then automatically expand that fold. (The "more than X %" condition might be needed if there are blank lines at the beginning of the file since they don't get folded.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try (in your `vimrc`:

```
au BufReadPost *.pm normal zo
```

For reference: `:help :autocmd`, `:help BufReadPost`